# free form report with SSRS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2012

I need to create a free form report which contains questions (question groups contain groups of similar questions....for example personal information, medications, emergency contact information etc) and answers for each of the questions for person.
My query goes something like this:

```
SELECT   person.person_Id,
        ,question_group.name AS Question_Group
        ,question_instance.name AS QAsked
        ,question_instance.answer AS QAnswered
FROM    person 
        INNER JOIN question_group....
```

So when I create a list using SSRS, using this tutorial (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519552.aspx) the only thing that appears on my form is the first question and its matching answer for the person...however, I want to be able to show all the questions/answers for each person on a page (so I'm grouping by person_id), and then show the next person and his questions/answers on the next page.

How can I iterate through these questions for each person, and am I able to move each question around in order to design a form, so the first name, last name questions can appear at the top of the page,...the questions which deal with emergency contact would appear middle of the form, etc...

I'm using SQL 2012, Microsoft Visual Studio Shell 2010 as well as Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Report Builder 3.0

I would greatly appreciate your advice on how to accomplish this.
Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: I believe you'll be able to accomplish this much more easily by using a Table rather than a List.

Comment: @Sev09, can you be more specific on how to accomplish this with a table?

Comment: Sure thing.  From the tutorial you posted, simply insert a table instead of a list.  It's in the same section.  Let me know once you have your blank table and I'll walk you throw further.

Comment: @Sev09, ok, added a table. Let me know what's next.

Comment: next, follow this tutorial to finish the report: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220467.aspx.  I believe you should make the most detailed level "QAsked" and "QAnswered", then in the group above, group by "Question_Group", then the highest group would be Person_ID.  Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Sev09, this looks ok, however, I cannot move the questions around,...they just show right underneath each other which creates a very long report.  I need to be able to make these fields into a 'form' like so http://www.youngstyleseyecareonline.com/sites/812/welcome_form2914712.jpg

Comment: but no user interaction is required, right?  You just want to see how each user answered after the fact?  If that's the case, even better!  You can simply drag and drop textboxes and these fields into a report laid out exactly your linked form is organized.

Comment: OR, you could always use something like Microsoft Access, which is set up exactly for forms like this.

Comment: @Sev09. OK, I understand what you mean by drag and drop. I did that and only the first record is showing in my report. How can I make each record show for each page?

Comment: Hey, I think I found an article that explains exactly how to accomplish this:  http://www.tinaungphyoe.com/home/posts/convertingarecordintoapageinssrs